# DB unit testing for View object?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unit-testing, msdn

Is the possible or is it in practice to create db unit test cases for View objects?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to unit test views but not widely done, at least in my experience.

View unit tests provide value in cases where views includes complex criteria. Also, for trivial queries, one can assert expected meta-data.